# Не воспринимаются русские символы в квадратных скобках в PCRE регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

```
<?php
$phrase = "Я люблю PHP";
if (preg_match("/^Я любл[ю] PHP$/", $phrase)) {
echo "Выражение найдено";//почему не выводит на экран?
}
?>

<?php
$phrase = "Я люблU PHP";
if (preg_match("/^Я любл[U] PHP$/", $phrase)) {
echo "Выражение найдено";//Тут все выводит, английские символы воспринимаются нормально
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификатор u включает дополнительную функциональность PCRE, которая не совместима с Perl: шаблон и целевая строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки. Модификатор u доступен в PHP 4.1.0 и выше для Unix-платформ, и в PHP 4.2.3 и выше для Windows платформ.

```
<?php
$phrase = "Я люблю PHP";
if (preg_match("/^Я любл[ю] PHP$/u", $phrase)) {
echo "Выражение найдено";//будет выводится на экран, так как использован модификатор u
}
?>
```